# How to make bunch of stereo files from bunch of mono files with ffmpeg in bash?

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, command-line, converters

I have two folders "Left channel" and "Right channel". Each folder contains mono files with same names. Example: "Left channel" contains "A.wav", "B.wav", "C.wav" and "Right channel" contains "A.wav", "B.wav", "C.wav". I need to make stereo files for each mono files.

So I have to combine

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

and

```
for file in /dir/* do ffmpeg -i ...; done
```

How can I go through all mono files and make bunch of stereo files from these mono files with ffmpeg in bash?

Comment: [Here is the link to the ffmpeg wiki article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) on how to do such conversion. As for processing bunch of files, you need to write a script (shell/bat/python/etc). If you specify your environment, someone may be able to help you there.

Comment: play about with ffmpeg manually at a terminal to master ability to create a stereo output file from joining together left and right audio files ...  then as other comment asks do you have bash on your machine ?  its a shell language extremely handy for such tasks of automating what you can do yourself  ... open up a terminal and issue command   `bash` to see if its defined or not then if not get it installed if possible

Comment: @ScottStensland, @kesh I have bash. So I have to combine `ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3` and `for file in /dir/* do ffmpeg -i ...; done`

Comment: Looks like you got all the ingredients there. Sorry, I'm a mostly Windows guy, so can't really help you there. [This tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners) seems to be pretty complete. Good luck. (I suggest updating your post to include your findings if you want to attract others to help.)

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

lch="Left channel"; rch="Right channel" # directory names of wav files
for f in "dir/$lch/"*.wav; do
    fname=${f##*/}                      # filename such as "A.wav"
    outfile="output_${fname%.*}.mp3"    # output filename such as "output_A.mp3"
    if [[ -f dir/$lch/$fname && dir/$rch/$fname ]]; then
        echo ffmpeg -i "dir/$lch/$fname" -i "dir/$rch/$fname" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" "$outfile"
    fi
done
```

It just outputs the command line as a dry run. If the output looks good, drop `echo` and run again.
Please note the output of `echo` removes the double quotes around the filenames. If you copy the output of `echo` and execute it on the command line, it will not work well.